# EXCEL: How can I check for a keyword in a string, compare it to a range and return the corresponding value in that range?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I need to categorize data: I have a column with the description of the element I'm interested in. I want to check that description for a keyword, then check if that keyword is contained in for example column A of a separate table. If a match is found, I need returned the value in the next column (in this example column B) of the same separate table.

The attached screenshot shows how the data is organized. The column called Column1 is the output I need.

[image: []

I have actually found a solution, but it involves lots of nesting, I need to force the categories and keywords in the formula and I can't add all the conditions I need; this is the current formula:

`=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("keyword";cellWithDescription);"category";);"OTHER")`

And for more categories I repeat the formula instead of "OTHER":

`=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("keyword";cellWithDescription);"category";);IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("keyword2";cellWithDescription2);"category2";);"OTHER"))`

which is not ideal, especially with many categories. How can I accomplish the same task with a simpler and more efficient formula, possibly comparing the keyword to values in a table (and not inside the formula itself, as I did now)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
=INDEX(category,MATCH(1,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(keyword,cellWithDescription)),0),1)
```

enter as array formula, thus `ctrl`+`shift`+`enter` after copying the formula (curly brackets will appear around the formula)

Comment: I would remove the curly braces from your answer. I know you just put it there to indicate it is an array formula, but I've seen users think they should actually type the braces, which causes confusion. Anyway, +1

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Good point and thanks. I'm never sure if I should mention - changed it with your input, should be clear now

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot @Jo.lass for your answer, your solution works exactly as I wanted!

Comment: Nice, thanks for the feedback - Don't hesitate to upvote and mark as answered for future reference

Comment: I did, but I'm afraid I don't have the reputation for it to show, this was my first question here... but thanks again